# Number of modified files in git index

Tags: git

How can I find out the number of modified files in the index? That is to say, files that show as "modified" when running `git status`.

I know lots of visual git tools that do this, as well as shell add-ons that show the count next to the prompt, but I just don't see how to do it on the command line in a reasonable way.

Comment: Not sure to understand the question, you are looking for something like  `git status -s -uno | wc -l` ?

Comment: Looks like that's the answer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can get the number of modified file using :

```
git status -s -uno | wc -l
```

From the [git status documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status), `-s` give output in short format, and `-uno` does not show untrack files.

Answer (score 3):

#### TL;DR

You probably want either *HEAD vs work-tree* or *HEAD vs index*, or perhaps *HEAD vs index plus index vs work-tree*.  If you want to keep the two comparisons separate, you cannot do it in one step.

#### Long description

There are several possible answers depending on precisely what question you meant.  Note that for all of the diff commands below, you can use `--name-only` if you're not interested in the particular change(s) in the file(s).  The status letter (Added, Deleted, Modified, etc.) is useful if you decide to add `--diff-filter` to choose to examine only specific kinds of changes.  For instance, if you want to know how many files are strictly *modified*, not counting files added or deleted, you could filter on `M`.

1. `git diff --cached --name-status HEAD | wc -l`
2. `git diff --name-status HEAD | wc -l`
3. `git diff --name-status | wc -l`
4. `git status -s -uno | wc -l` (as in [mpromonet's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47146064/number-of-modified-files-in-git-index#comment81242592_47146064)).

Each produces a different result:

1. Compares `HEAD` to the index: what would be different in the commit you would make now if you ran `git commit` right now, compared to what's in the commit that is `HEAD` right now?  That is, you have a current commit *now*, and if you make a new commit, the current commit will be the new commit's parent.  What will be different?

   (Remember, the index represents the *next* commit to make.  It starts out with copies of the exact same files as in `HEAD`.  Each time you `git add` a file, you copy the file back from the work-tree, into the index.  This is therefore comparing what you *will* commit now if you commit, to what you have in your `HEAD` commit.  As a special case here, you can omit the name `HEAD`; `--cached` will assume `HEAD`.)

   In the long `git status` output, these come out in the first section: `Changes to be committed`.
2. Compares `HEAD` to the work-tree.  These are files that are modified in the work-tree, but are *not* staged for commit.  In the longer `git status` output, these *generally* come out in the second section, `Changes not staged for commit`—but see the very next bit.
3. Compares the index to the work-tree.  These, too, are files that are modified in the work-tree—but this time they're changed with respect to the files already copied back into the index.  To the extent that the index matches the `HEAD` commit, #2 and #3 produce the same list of files.  But suppose `README` is in `HEAD` as Version H (for Head).  You  modify `README` and `git add README`, copying version W (for Work-tree) into version I (for Index).  Then you modify version W *again*.  Now all three are different!  Using `git status --short` or `git status -s`, you will see `MM README` in the output: it's modified twice.

   The output from this section is really what shows up in the second half of the `git status` output, the `Changes not staged for commit` part.
4. Compares `HEAD` vs index, then compares index vs work-tree, then prints—in a summary, combined format—the name and status of each file, using *two* letters for each file.

To illustrate this clearly, consider this repository with a single initial commit, with one file in it.  The file is named `README` and the initial commit version contains the text `Read me.`

```
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in ...
$ echo 'Read me.' > README
$ git add README
$ git commit -m initial
[master (root-commit) a9362c4] initial
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 README
$ echo 'Please read me.' > README
$ git add README
$ echo 'Read me, for I am very readable.' > README
```

There are now three active versions of file `README`, and:

```
$ git status -s
MM README
```

The long version of `git status` shows us that `README` is both ready to commit, and has changes not staged for commit:

```
$ git status
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        modified:   README

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   README
```

Look, though, at what happens if we put the initial text back, then compare `HEAD` to the work-tree:

```
$ echo 'Read me.' > README
$ git diff --name-status HEAD
$
```

The current commit matches the work-tree, so there is no difference here.  If you `git add README`, the short status goes from `MM README` to empty:

```
$ git status -s
MM README
$ git add README
$ git status -s
$
```

So, if you are wondering "what do I get if I add and commit everything", you will want to compare `HEAD` with the work-tree.  If you are wondering "what do I get if I commit now", you want to compare `HEAD` to index.

Comment: Thanks for this in-depth answer. Let me make sure I have the terms right: HEAD is the commit currently checked out, the same as when you `git status` and it outputs "On branch $foo". The index is what would get turned into a commit if you said `git commit`. The work tree is basically the state of your project on the file system. Please check me if I've got any of that mixed up.

Comment: Yep, that's exactly right. Well, in even more detail, `HEAD` normally contains the *name of the branch*, $foo in your case, and then the branch name contains the commit hash, which makes looking up the hash a two-step process—but much of the time, Git just looks up the commit hash from `HEAD`, as if it were all one thing.

Answer (score 3):

Since this questions is about finding the *count* of changes, there are a couple git commands that do this natively, without having to add `| wc -l` to your command

You can use [`git diff`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff) with the following args:

- [`--stat`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt---statltwidthgtltname-widthgtltcountgt) - generate a diffstat
- [`--numstat`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt---numstat) - shows number of added and deleted lines in decimal notation
- [`--shortstat`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt---shortstat) - only the last line of the --stat

```sh
$ git diff --stat

src/models/models.ts | 5 +++++
src/utils/git.ts     | 9 ++++++---
2 files changed, 11 insertions(+), 3 deletions(-)
```

```sh
$ git diff --numstat

5       0       src/models/models.ts
6       3       src/utils/git.ts
```

```sh
$ git diff --shortstat

2 files changed, 11 insertions(+), 3 deletions(-)
```